# Python json module generates non-unique keys

Tags: python, json

According to JSON specification https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8259 object's keys should be unique

> 4. Objects
>
> An object structure is represented as a pair of curly brackets
> surrounding zero or more name/value pairs (or members).  A name is a
> string.  A single colon comes after each name, separating the name
> from the value.  A single comma separates a value from a following
> name.  **The names within an object SHOULD be unique**.

But it's possible to create json object with two same keys

```
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 23 2017, 16:37:01) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
>>> import json
>>> json.dumps({1: 'value1', "1": 'value2'})
'{"1": "value1", "1": "value2"}'
```

Is it an error?

Comment: No, it is your responsibility to pass a dictionary where the keys will render different output.

Comment: Your given data has unique keys. One is the integer `1`, the other is a string of length one containing `"1"`. btw `json` can only have string keys in objects.

Comment: @quamrana, yes, my dict has different keys, I know, I'm talking about resulting json object

Comment: So, if you were to make a `dict` which was compatible with `json`, then `json.dumps()` would produce valid `json`. What happens if you take that output string and pass that into `json.loads()`?

Comment: @quamrana, `{'1': 'value2'}` because it's python's dict and dict doesn't support multiple same keys, but there isn't only python, that output may be sent to another application which expects unique keys

Comment: Well, at some computing expense, you could always do this round trip: `dict`-> `invalid json` -> `dict` -> `valid json`.

Comment: Note that `json.load` provides an `object_pairs_hook` keyword argument which you can use to correctly load objects with duplicate keys without suffering data loss.

Answer (score 4):

In the [JSON spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159#section-4), the object (like a dict) is:

> An object structure is represented as a pair of curly brackets
> surrounding zero or more name/value pairs (or members).  **A name is a
> string.**

Emphasis mine.  **Python's `json.dumps` is very forgiving with the input object.**  It will implicitly convert integer keys to strings, and this can result in data loss / key collisions just as you've seen here.  It also breaks the round trip `loads(dumps(d))`.

If the data loss is a concern in your context, consider to use a stricter json library, e.g.

```
>>> import demjson  # pip install demjson
>>> demjson.encode({1: 'value1', "1": 'value2'}, strict=True)
# JSONEncodeError: ('object properties (dictionary keys) must be strings in strict JSON', 1)
```

> Is it error?

In my opinion, yes.  I've seen a lot of bugs caused by this, and would prefer if the stdlib `json.dumps` was strict by default, with an *opt-in* keyword argument for enabling any implicit conversions.  However, the chances of this getting changed in Python are approximately zero.

Answer (score 3):

The JSON RFC says "keys SHOULD be unique."  RFCs have a very specific meaning for "SHOULD."  From https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2119:

> SHOULD: This word, or the adjective "RECOMMENDED", mean that there
> may exist valid reasons in particular circumstances to ignore a
> particular item, but the full implications must be understood and
> carefully weighed before choosing a different course.

So JSON is not forbidden to have duplicate keys, though it is undesirable, and I would recommend against it.

If you want to check that your dict is good, you can use this test:

```
def keys_are_unique(d):
    return len(d) == len(set(str(k) for k in d))
```

Comment: Alternative test: `d == json.loads(json.dumps(d))`

Comment: The dictionary in the OP's question, `{1: 'value1', "1": 'value2'}`, would be considered valid by your `keys_are_unique()` function.