# json.dump records exactly two copies of dict items

Tags: python, json

I am trying to have a `dict` stored in a json file, to be read and edited every time my script is run. I have found that `json.dump` leaves the first copy of the edited key-value and appends the second, but when run again the original key-value is removed and the first replacement is retained along with the new key-value. For example, if `file.json` is initially set to `{}` and we have code like this:

```py
import json
with open('file.json') as file:
    data = json.load(file)
data[0] = 1
with open('file.json', 'w') as file:
    json.dump(data, file)
```

The first time through `file.json` will be `{'0':1}`, the second time it will be `{'0':1, '0':1}`, and so too the third and fourth times.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python json module generates non-unique keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48478339/python-json-module-generates-non-unique-keys)

Answer (score -1):

The problem was that I was accessing the new data with a numeric key, but json always stores the key as a string. Because of that, the new `data[0]` is not the same as `data['0']` taken from `json.load`, and `data` becomes `{'0':1, 0:1}`. `json.dump` is happy with that two-item `dict`, and puts it in the json file. But there it converts the numeric key to a string, and it doesn't do like python to overwrite the first item with that identical key. When the `dict` is loaded the next time the script is run, python finds a duplicate key, and the first value is overwritten, so at that point `data` is `{'0':1}`, ready to accept an added key-value `{0:1}`.